# Grabbing object from user in parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In a collection view I have an array of events and each cell has a background image view of the event image which is saved as a PFFile. That works fine and good until I added this code. The user has a property "profilePicture" which I want to display in the cell as well. Here is my code which is inside of the block which gets the event image.

```
let eventCreator : PFUser = event?.objectForKey("user") as! PFUser
let creatorImage : PFFile = eventCreator.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
creatorImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

    cell.creatorImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

})
```

Here is the full method which gets the event and all it's properties (like which I said, worked perfectly fine before I added the above code. Now it throws an "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. Any help?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //sets up cell

    let cell : EventCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventCell

    //adds attend action

    cell.attendButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    //queries parse for events

    let event = events?[indexPath.row]

    event?.eventImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

        if let data = data, image = UIImage(data: data) {

            if cell.isFlipped == false {

            cell.eventBackgroundImage.image = image
            cell.eventTitleLabel.text = event?.eventTitle

            //gets profile picture of events creator

            let eventCreator : PFUser = event?.objectForKey("user") as! PFUser
            let creatorImage : PFFile = eventCreator.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
            creatorImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                cell.creatorImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            })

            //sets correct category for cell image

                if event?.category == "" {
                    cell.categoryImageView.image = nil
                }

                if event?.category == "The Arts" {
                    cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "University")
                }

                if event?.category == "The Outdoors" {
                    cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Landscape")
                }

                //TODO finish categories

            }

            else if cell.isFlipped == true {

                cell.eventDescriptionLabel.text = event?.eventDescription
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcefully casting a nil-valued optional variable to a non-optional one will lead to a runtime error. Why are you using `as!` operator ? You should probably use the `as?` operator instead and check for any `nil` values to make sure the cast was successful before doing anything.

**[Edit]**
Try something like this:

```
if let eventCreator = event?.objectForKey("user") as? PFUser {
    if let creatorImage = eventCreator.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
        creatorImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

            cell.creatorImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that would make more sense but it throws an error when I put as? and tells me to change it back.

Comment: Of course it will complain. You need to rewrite thoses two lines with `if let` instead.

Comment: I figured but am not sure the order or syntax. Obviously putting "if" in front of the let doesn't work by itself, would you be able to show me an example of the code you were thinking of?

Comment: Okay a step in the right direction but I get an error on the "self.cell.creatorImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)" line saying... "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: For some reason it doesn't autocomplete the getDataInBackground with block part o after the creatorImage as it should be doing.

Comment: I had to remove `self` from code as you defined it locally.